# Can't connect Coldfusion 10 to mysql 5

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I am trying to setup a test coldfusion server running on my home PC (Windows 8 Pro 64 bit). I have Coldfusion 10 installed, and mysql 5.6.10 working as well. When I try to connect them, I am getting the following error:

```
Connection verification failed for data source: 
mydbcom.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: 
Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. 
Giving up.
The root cause was that: 
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: 
Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
```

I've looked all over the place, and I can't seem to figure out what I need to do to fix it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you connect to the MySQL server from the CF server without going through cf? (Command line, MySQL workbench, etc.)

Comment: To be completely honest, I have no idea how to do that.  I'm not much of a DBA. Most if not all of the databases that I use have already been setup and connected. Mainly Oracle, Sql Server, and DB2.  This is really the first time I am setting up a system from scratch, and since mysql is free, I'm using it.

Comment: If you're sure how to connect to the database without CF, you may be in over your head in setting this up.

Answer (score 2):

What's your DSN definition in CF Admin look like? Did you create a MySQL user that has access to that database, which you then used in your CF Admin DSN connection?

**EDIT:**

Yes, you should never connection as "root" by practice. Create a new user and give them the correct permissions to your database. I've got some instructions here if you need them.

http://iknowkungfoo.com/blog/index.cfm/2008/6/16/The-ACME-Guide-64bit-Ubuntu-804-Edition-Part-3

Comment: CF Data Source: mydb  Database: mysql56  Server: 127.0.0.1 Port: 3306 username: root Password:****   I am connecting to mysql using the root user.  Should I create another user to connect with?

Comment: @RobM I personally don't think so.  It's your home computer.  You're not in a production environment and security shouldn't be an issue unless you actually plan on using your home machine to do any kind of external hosting.

Comment: @KRC I agree with you completely.  This is my home machine, and I'm not going to be running anything external from it. Just for dev.

Answer (score 0):

The trick for me was to type in the IP address for the server address when adding a new CF ADMIN DSN entry. Using local, localhost or 127.0.0.1 for the server address did not work for me.